# Pandas: breaking ties for mode

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Is there a neat way to break ties when mode() returns several values, i.e. in a multi-modal distribution.  For context I am implementing a voting system and I want to break ties in a custom, non-random way.

In the following artificial example, I want the mode for each row, but if there are several modes, I want to prefer the one with the shortest name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig']
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {c : [random.choice(fruits)
          for _ in range(10)]
     for c in "ABCDEF"}
)

print(d,"\n")
print(d.mode(axis=1))
```

The output shows the initial data frame and the default output of `pandas.DataFrame.mode()`

```txt
            A           B           C           D           E           F
0        date  elderberry         fig  elderberry        date         fig
1        date      banana  elderberry       apple  elderberry         fig
2       apple  elderberry      banana      cherry      cherry       apple
3      cherry      banana      cherry        date       apple  elderberry
4  elderberry      cherry       apple      cherry  elderberry        date
5        date      banana         fig  elderberry       apple      cherry
6        date       apple       apple         fig       apple      banana
7      cherry  elderberry         fig      banana         fig         fig
8        date      cherry      cherry  elderberry        date      cherry
9      cherry  elderberry        date        date         fig         fig 

            0           1       2     3           4    5
0        date  elderberry     fig   NaN         NaN  NaN
1  elderberry         NaN     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
2       apple      cherry     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
3      cherry         NaN     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
4      cherry  elderberry     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
5       apple      banana  cherry  date  elderberry  fig
6       apple         NaN     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
7         fig         NaN     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
8      cherry         NaN     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
9        date         fig     NaN   NaN         NaN  NaN
```

I have posted my own attempt as an answer, but is there a neater way to do this?  In any case, I hope it might help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: After you get the mode, you want to order the non-NaN elements in a row using some custom function, is this understanding correct? :)

Comment: Yes @zabop, and my attempt to do this is below, but I wondered if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my attempt, I use `apply()` on each row to gather all mode values (dropping NAs first), then do a custom sort using my own (name-length) score as the `key` parameter to python's `sorted()`.  The first item is then the one we want.  Of course, this solution does not deal with "what it there are two modal values with the same length?", but the tiebreaker function can be develoepd as necessary for any given scenario.

```py
def myscore(fruitname):
    return len(fruitname)

def breakties(row):
    modes = list(row.dropna())
    return sorted(modes, key=myscore)[0]

print("Mode with ties broken")
print(d.mode(axis=1).apply(breakties, axis=1))

print("OR, more succinctly")
print(
    d.mode(axis=1).apply(
        lambda row: sorted(list(row.dropna()),key=lambda v:len(v))[0],
        axis=1
    )
)
```

````txt
Mode with ties broken
0           fig
1    elderberry
2         apple
3        cherry
4        cherry
5           fig
6         apple
7           fig
8        cherry
9           fig
dtype: object
OR, more succinctly
0           fig
1    elderberry
2         apple
3        cherry
4        cherry
5           fig
6         apple
7           fig
8        cherry
9           fig
dtype: object```
````